# Laravel form with RESTful Controller: "Some mandatory parameters are missing"

Tags: forms, rest, controller, laravel

I keep getting this error "Some mandatory parameters are missing" and I can't find how to resolve it.

This is my DataController:

```
//use some models here for Trialdata, Sessions, Rat;
class DataController extends \BaseController {

 //Some functions

public function destroy($id)
{
            Trialdata::where('id', $id)->delete();
            Sessions::where('id', $id)->update(array('sD_reason', 'Excluded'));
            Sessions::where('id', $id)->delete();
            Rat::where('id', $id)->update(array('sD_reason', Input::get('sD_reason')));
            Rat::where ('id', $id)->delete(); 
            //
}
}
```

This is my route:

```
Route::resource('data', 'DataController');
```

This is the form in my view:

```
{{Form::open(array('route' => 'data.destroy', $parameters = array($entry[0]->id)))}}

    {{Form::label('sD_reason', 'Please specify the reasons of the exclusion');}}<br>
    <input name="sD_reason" type="text" id="sD_reason"> 
    <button type="button">No, thanks</button>
    <button type="submit" href="#">Exclude</butfon>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

I've look around for similar problems and I believe it's in my `Form::open` but I can't find the proper syntax.

Comment: $parameters = array($entry[0]->id - What are you trying to do there? That's gibberish inside an associative array

Comment: I'm try to pass my `$id` for my `DataController@destroy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{{ Form::open( array('route' => array('data.destroy', $entry[0]->id) ) ) }}
```

From the docs:
http://laravel.com/docs/html#opening-a-form

Comment: Working... I thought I tried that. Well, that wasn't a good question in perspective. Thanks for your help